# Run query within IF statement

Tags: c#, vb6

I'm trying to learn C# and have come across a problem that I hope you guys will know an easy solution.

I want to run two possible LINQ queries but reading from different places and returning a 2 different fields (both id's) based on an IF condition.

In VB6 it would have been something simple like:

```
Dim strQuery as string
Dim rs as adodb.recordset

If 1 = 1 then
    strQuery = "Select messageid as id1, refid as id1 from x where ..."
else
    strQuery = "Select commonid as id1, nextid as id2 from x where ..."
endif

set rs = cn.execute(strquery)

debug.print rs!id1 & rs!id2
```

How can this be done in c#?

I've tried:
                IQueryable fD = null;

```
            if (1 == 1)
            {
                fD = from qa in data.table1
                        select qa;
            }
            else
            {
                fD = from qa in data.table2
                        select qa;
            }

            foreach (var a in FD)
            {
                // Unable to see any data.
            }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ. Apart from this this should be more or less the same in C#, except that there´s no `End If` and `Dim` but just some brackets that define the scope. So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: LINQ returns `IQueryable` collection after doing query functions, so `IQueryable strQuery` then using `strQuery = x.Where(...).Select(x => new { id1 = x.commonid, id2 = x.nextid });` should be consider then.

Comment: What have you tried in c#? Are you perhaps trying to use LINQ to SQL?

Comment: The fact that OP is importing `adodb.recordset` in his `usings` makes me assume that Linq won´t help here as every statement is just created as a simple string passed to the ADO-connection. Thus all we can do about this question is suggest to use Linq2Sql instead of ADO and close this question as this would be far too broad.

Comment: HimBromBeere - the question has nothing to do VB6 or ADO, they are examples of how it could be done in VB6. I'm looking to do it using LINQ in c# as my question states.

Comment: This is a forum for VB6! Nothing to do with C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou Tetsuya Yamamoto for pointing me in the right direction **IQueryable strQuery**

```
          foreach (**dynamic** a in strQuery)
            {
                //a.CentralContractorID
            }
```

dynamic was the word which was missing, it now works perfect.